# Handle traffic over network bridge

Tags: networking, firewall, switch, local-area-network, bridge

I have 2 network, LAN1 connected with some hosts and the second LAN2 with proprietary Hardware, similar to PLCs. This kind of PLC is connected via Ethernet and is used for home automation (ie Light control, Shades positioning etc..) and all works fine.

```
                __________               __________
[HOST1] -------|          |             |          |---[PLC1]
               |  SWITCH  |             |  SWITCH  |
[HOST2] -------|   LAN1   |             |   LAN2   |---[PLC2]
               |__________|             |__________|
```

Some hosts of LAN1 need to communicate with PLC to be able to send commands and to administer their web interface.
So I have connected the two LAN, connecting SWITCH1 with SWITCH2:

```
                __________               __________
[HOST1] -------|          |             |          |---[PLC1]
               |  SWITCH  |             |  SWITCH  |
[HOST2] -------|   LAN1   |-------------|   LAN2   |---[PLC2]
               |__________|             |__________|
```

But when i connect LAN1 to LAN2, PLCs automation actions no longer work correctly. I think is a traffic issue: The PLCs are disturbed by the heavy communication of the LAN1.

I have to connect LAN1 with LAN2 because PLC uses a proprietary protocol that work over broadcast UDP commands on a specific port (ie port 37001). This commands must be also received and sent by some Hosts in LAN1.

Is there a way to filter packets passing through LAN1 and LAN2? For example opening only the specific UDP port and HTTP port (UDP 37001 and TCP 80). Which kind of hardware/software i need to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Are there different address spaces in LAN1 / LAN2?

Comment: currently LAN1 and LAN2 have the same address spaces: 192.168.1.1/24 but there is no problem to change it...

Answer (score 2):

You should assign two different subnets for the LANs, and then add a router between them that filters traffic according to your requirements.

Filtering cannot be (at least easily) done using only Ethernet level mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you. Is required a special router to preserve broadcast on port 37001 between LAN1 and LAN2?

Comment: @AndreaBoc Routers do not forward broadcasts.  If you need broadcasts, then you must connect the LANs together -- which makes then essentially one LAN.  Switches will only forward traffic to PLC1 (for example) if the traffic is destined for that device, or it is a broadcast. PLC1 will never see traffic between Host 1 and 2, for example.  That may affect your conclusion about too much traffic.